# Receiving messages from RabbitMQ using reactive Java

Tags: java, rabbitmq, deserialization, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am quite a newbie to Reactive Programming in Java. I am making a project that receives messages from RabbitMQ. I use reactive RabbitMQ API -> (https://projectreactor.io/docs/rabbitmq/snapshot/reference/). It uses specific classes for sending and receiving messages - OutboundMessage and Delivery classes respectively. When I receive message of type Delivery it has field of bytes array which I need to deserialize into my custom Class, cause I know that when a message is sent to RabbitMQ, Java object was serialized and put into OutboundMessage in field body of type byte[]. The Problem is I am trying to deserialize it via ObjectInputStream which probably has a certain conflict with Flux.

```
@Configuration
public class MessagingRabbitmqExecutorApplicationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    Mono<Connection> connectionMono() {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.useNio();
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> connectionFactory.newConnection("rabbit")).cache();
    }

    @Bean
    public SenderOptions senderOptions(Mono<Connection> connectionMono) {
        return new SenderOptions()
                .connectionMono(connectionMono)
                .resourceManagementScheduler(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
    }

    @Bean
    public Sender sender(SenderOptions senderOptions) {
        return RabbitFlux.createSender(senderOptions);
    }

    @Bean
    public ReceiverOptions receiverOptions(Mono<Connection> connectionMono) {
        return new ReceiverOptions()
                .connectionMono(connectionMono)
                .connectionSubscriptionScheduler(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
    }

    @Bean
    public Receiver receiver(ReceiverOptions receiverOptions) {
        return RabbitFlux.createReceiver(receiverOptions);
    }
}

.
.
.
.
.

Flux<CustomModel> messages = receiver.consumeNoAck("queue")
                .map(this::deliveryToCustomModel)
                .doOnNext(//do something)
                .doOnError(//handle error)
                .subscribe();
.
.
.
.
.

private CustomModel deliveryToCustomModel(Delivery delivery) {
        CustomModel model = null;
        try (ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(delivery.getBody()))) {
            model = (CustomModel) inputStream.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return model;
    }
```

I always get error message printed out from catch block. I am getting {invalid stream header: 4D657373} when I print out e.getMessage(). I assume something is wrong in try with resources when I am trying to get the resources. How can Object be deserialized from byte[] in Flux?

As you can see I pass that mapper-method as a function to map method and anticipate to get my CustomModel class to operate with it in my own way. But I need proper deserialization in flux.